# Gzip EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big file and I'm trying to read and rewrite it. But some lines in the file seem to be corrupted and I am encountering an error that prevents me from rewriting the entire file.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\makesmall.py", line 9, in <module>
    for i in fin.readlines():
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 399, in readline
    return self._buffer.readline(size)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\gzip.py", line 507, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Code:

```
with open("small.txt","a") as save:
    with gzip.open('big.txt.gz','rb') as fin:
            for i in fin.readlines():
                    save.write(str(i))
```

If I use "try except" the file write process does not continue. Is there a way to just skip the bad lines?

Comment: There is no "bad lines", you do not seems to understand the error. The file is corrupted, not "some lines" (which has no sens when you're not talking of a text file) : the code has reached the end of the file (it has read all the bytes) BUT it doesn't end with the expected specific bytes

Comment: @azro Is there a solution you can suggest?

Comment: You came to the end of the file. Data is missing and cannot be recovered from this file. You could catch the EOFError so that your new file closes properly - but you won't get all of the data, it just isn't there. It may be helpful to have _some_ data, but usually one would delete "small.txt" completely (or rename to something like "small.txt.partial") so that it isn't confused with a complete file.

Comment: If you have control of the thing that wrote this file, look at fixing the problem at the source. It appears that another script had an error but instead of deleting the .gz file completely, it let a corrupt one hang around.